# Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12582920 bytes) error laravel

Tags: php, mysql, memory, laravel-5.6

I am trying to load entire data from a table that has approximately 3 million records.

```
$records_all = DB::table('some_table')
               ->selectRaw('*')
               ->get();
```

But this gives me error:

```
Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12582920 bytes) error laravel
```

I tried increasing the size of `memory_limit` in `php.ini` from `128M` to `512M`
still the same error occurs.

I also tried other solutions provided on stackoverflow but nothing worked.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Try to use pagintion, 3 million records is a lotand it will crash your browser before it crashes the server

Comment: Fetch less data at once, period. Even just UX-wise, what are you going to do with 3m of anything on one page?

Comment: @getl0st it is not possible for me to use pagination as im trying to display a report.

Comment: @Raj you cant have 3 million records in a page

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, 3 million records is too much, I see that you are using laravel, you can try and read [this documentation page](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination) in order to understand how to paginate something

Comment: One more thing, even when I remove the view logic for displaying still the query itself gives this error even if I dont pass it to the view

Comment: Then there is something in your data that is causing the problem. It most likely unescaped data being processing incorrectly.

Comment: It gives an error because you are out of memory! You cannot just simply load 3 million records out of your database